# Can't find an element

Tags: python, angular, selenium, element

I'm trying to find an element using Python 3.10.5 and Selenium 4.2.0.

The problem is: The program works fine until I reach some point.

[image: the screen]

I want to access the element marked in red. When I see the page source, this element is not there, but when I try to inspect the element, I can see him, but I can't select in code trying to find by xpath, css path and others.

```
<div _ngcontent-rye-c7="">
    <a _ngcontent-rye-c7="" title="Minutar decisão" href="#/painel-usuario-interno/lista-processos-tarefa/Minutar%20decis%C3%A3o/eyJudW1lcm9Qcm9jZXNzbyI6IiIsImNvbXBldGVuY2lhIjoiIiwiZXRpcXVldGFzIjpbXX0%3D">
        <div _ngcontent-rye-c7="" class="detalheTarefasQuantidade">
            <span _ngcontent-rye-c7="" class="nome">Minutar decisão</span><span _ngcontent-rye-c7="" class="quantidadeTarefa">545</span><
        /div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I checked this part and is inside an IFRAME with ID "ngFrame", when I try to show only this frame, the data is not show and an Angular favicon is show on page title.

[image: angular]

Can anyone has some idea how can I find this element in my code? If need more information, please ask.

Thank you!

Update 01: Python Source Code:

```
import os
import logging

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common import keys
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

class TaggerBot:
    def __init__(self):
        logging.getLogger('WDM').setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
        options = Options()
        #options.add_argument('--headless')
        os.environ['GH_TOKEN'] = ':)'
        service = Service(GeckoDriverManager().install())
        self.driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)

    def startup(self, webpage):
        self.driver.get(webpage)

        login_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"loginAplicacaoButton\"]")
        login_button.click()
        print("Você está logado!")

        rule_bar = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li/a")
        rule_bar.click()
        select_rule = Select(self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"papeisUsuarioForm:usuarioLocalizacaoDecoration:usuarioLocalizacao\"]"))
        select_rule.select_by_index(1)
        print("Você está na lista de tarefas.")

    def select_task(self):
        # Here I want to select the task "Minutar decisão"
        print(self.driver.page_source)

    def quit(self):
        self.driver.quit()

    def execute(self):
        self.startup("link to page")
        self.select_task()
        self.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = TaggerBot()
    b.execute()
```

Update 02: Full HTML Source Code for the first screen: [full source code](https://pastebin.com/fe7ZBef8)

Update 03: Relevante code for IFRAME:

```
<iframe id="ngFrame" name="ngFrame" class="ng-frame"></iframe>
(...)
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('ngFrame').src = 'https://frontend.prd.cnj.cloud/' + location.hash;
if (!window.PJe) {
     window.PJe = {};
}
            
PJe.CONSTANTES = {
    CODIGO_SEGURANCA: 'VAjonOyQlrbUpVjrcyi7e7wXlEuf9u8W17SE/vNBlWBsuio16HVW9baXbOBF2RQrvTSFfwymXmjDfM/T0nWwLyv6zr5PZhxKbG9FNkgZLuhnyjx2wfUaYhGlV04VJ43yCV/1n+hLc1uq7Elr31+J9UpkKyK7x4PKkIH+MlJqDcWwHccWOPqXX1PjIFgfJmaUyE5DJBkZWY0/TP5mZnJo3Ch2VdSx1aRqSw88kmmMkuiT3m20OWXFr0KvIzyfLNyktdZP7Du3Fo56RjQySNfekrr9rlwJDhaz8CTsz9IselSvaMAY5DIFbXZH3OmXHQcMTF6evF7dQHZl2/6ti34hkQ==',
     WEB_ROOT: 'https://pje2.tjma.jus.br/pje2g',
     TIPO_JUSTICA: 'JC',
     TIPO_EDITOR: 'TN',
     PATH: '/pje2g',
     JSESSIONID: PJe.getCookie("JSESSIONID"),
     PJELEGACYStickySessionRule: PJe.getCookie('PJE-TJMA-2G' + "-StickySessionRule"),
     PJE_APP_NAME: 'pje-tjma-2g',
     PJE_GATEWAY_SERVICE: 'https://gateway.prd.cnj.cloud',
     COOKIES: document.cookie,
     INSTANCIA: '2',
     MOBILE: 'false',
     CORS_ENABLED: 'true',
     ID_USUARIO_LOCALIZACAO: '70753',
     SSO_ENABLED: 'false'
}; 
            
pjePayload = {
   TYPE: "pje-payload",
   CONSTANTES: PJe.CONSTANTES
};
            
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {
    if(event.data.NG_CLIENT) {
          window.frames["ngFrame"].postMessage(JSON.parse( JSON.stringfy(pjePayload)),"https://frontend.prd.cnj.cloud");
    }

    if(event.data.CONTEUDO_TAREFA_FULLSCREEN){
                         
        jQuery('#barraSuperiorPrincipal').toggleClass("hidden");
    }
                
}           
</script>
```

Comment: if you want help i suggest you to show your code...and the link if possible or the source code of html page, the idea is to reproduce the problem

Comment: Hi @Frenchy I will update showing the sources required.

Comment: @sksdutra Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). You may like to consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Hi @undetectedSelenium I changed the HTML image for the relevant code for the part. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please select/switch to that iframe and then apply findelement with XPath. Please share complete iframe content so that I can build XPath for you. Once the element is selected and all the required operations are done, switch to defaultContent(). T

Comment: Hi @naeem-ahmed, thanks for the answer. The first thing I try is switch to the iframe, but unfortunately not work...

I'll update the question with the relevante code for the iframe.

Comment: Hi, I the Update 03 I write the code related to iframe/ngFrame (aNGular Frame?). It appears the contents of IFRAME is being generated dinamically. So, how can I access the contents generated dinamically inside the iframe?

Comment: I was also faced same problem to find element inside iframe and I fixed by switching and switching back from iframe. My working code is in C#.

Comment: Is that works for you if I share?.

Comment: Hi @naeem-ahmed, I think I can read a little C#, so it'll be useful. I'll try switch in and switch out the IFRAME, and see what happens. I'll post feedback about this as soon I test this solution. Thank you!